# error while re-installing apache2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache2

I remove apache from my machine following these steps:

`sudo apt-get remove apache2*`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo rm -Rf /etc/apache2`

I was able to remove it successfully but when I tried to install it again I got this error:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
```

I tried to fix it whit this command

`sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install apache2`

but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get remove does not remove configuration files, and you probably touched that file and messed it up so reinstalling without purging configuration will not work. So try this approach instead:

```
apt-get purge apache2
```

and then:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

envvars file comes in apache2 package and default should include all the necessary variables, you can brwose and check it yourself from [envvars search at packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=envvars&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)